# Deviation from a trend- Help to define the problem

Tags: trend

I am trying to define a problem I have in proper statistical terms. Here's what I have:

I have a set of values measured monthly. These values are expected to grow pretty steadily over time. I need to identify the values that deviate from the trend. All values are >= 0.

I need to do the above for quite a few data sets, and values in them can be as small as 1 and up to few hundred thousands.

I am doing my analysis in Oracle database. It has quite a few statistical functions, but because I don't what I am looking for, I don't know which ones would be useful for me.